# PEP8 and long method names from imported modules

Tags: python, pep8

I can't seem to find a question on this, but I'm having issues maintaining PEP8 because of a module I've imported.

I'm using the TextGridTools (tgt) module to parse TextGrid files, format for annotating spoken audio files. The problem is it has functions with ghastly long names such as `get_annotations_between_timepoints`.

Because I'm using it inside a class method with loops, conditionals, and a list comprehension, it's already significantly indented:

```
def align_intervals(self):
  print('Aligning intervals...')
  brk = self.brk_intervals
  all_atts = self.all_attributes

  word_list = []
    for i in range(len(brk)):
      if i == 0:
        word_list.append([att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(0, brk[0].time) for att in all_atts])
      else:
        word_list.append([att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(brk[i-1].time, brk[i].time) for att in all_atts])
  return word_list
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: IMHO the 80 character limit is outdated. It makes sense when you are programming in a terminal on a screen from the '80s. Today everyone has way bigger screens. I'd say 120 or 150 are much more reasonable limits. Obviously if you can keep lines shorter better, but I don't see any reason to change your code at all. So maybe the only change would be disabling that rule in your linter...

Comment: I think I can get behind this. Haha!

Comment: Another suggestion is that you might want to consider removing the if statement. Manually insert the 0th condition, then start your for loop on 1... That way you're not doing an if check on every single `i` past 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the line between parentheses with no ill effects. In fact, the official PEP-8 docs say as much:

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

```
def align_intervals(self):
    print('Aligning intervals...')
    brk = self.brk_intervals
    all_atts = self.all_attributes

    word_list = []
    for i in range(len(brk)):
        if i == 0:
            word_list.append([
                att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(
                    0, brk[0].time
                ) for att in all_atts
            ])
        else:
            word_list.append([
                att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(
                    brk[i - 1].time, brk[i].time
                ) for att in all_atts
            ])
    return word_list
```

An alternative would be to alias the long functions with a shorter local variable:

```
get_tpts = att.get_annotations_between_timepoints
```

Then use that alias where needed.

Comment: This looks **way worse** than the original code and is harder to read.

Comment: Whether or not it looks ugly is beside the point. The official PEP lists this as the solution for wrapping long lines.

Comment: I went ahead and aliased the function. I still had to break it to a new line on the list comprehension's for loop, but now it's much more readable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Silverwing171: Aliasing things is fine—it's done all the time. Also often makes it easier to change things because you only have to do it in one place. Adding a level of indirection has been called the "first law" of software engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the long method names a short name yourself:

```
import package

short_method = package.ungodly_ridiculous_long_name_for_a_method
short_class = package.another_ungodly_unnecessarily_long_name_for_a_class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just insert some line breaks:

```
def align_intervals(self):
    print('Aligning intervals...')
    brk = self.brk_intervals
    all_atts = self.all_attributes

    word_list = []
        for i in range(len(brk)):
        if i == 0:
            word_list.append(
                [
                    att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(0, brk[0].time) 
                    for att in all_atts
                ]
            )
      else:
        word_list.append(
            [
                att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(brk[i-1].time, brk[i].time) 
                for att in all_atts
            ]
        )
  return word_list
```

There's no definitive answer for code style because it's a subjective thing after all. [`Black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) recently introduced a code formatter that's pretty nice IMO. But in the end, just do what you / your teams likes best.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- define alias, like suggested by Jonah Bishop
- refactor code and make function that will return the list
- refactor the code to decrease level of indentation

So you can replace

```
word_list = []
    for i in range(len(brk)):
        if i == 0:
            word_list.append([
                att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(
                    0, brk[0].time
                ) for att in all_atts
            ])
        else:
            word_list.append([
                att.get_annotations_between_timepoints(
                    brk[i - 1].time, brk[i].time
                ) for att in all_atts
            ])
```

with

```
    def gabt(brk0, brk1, all_atts):
        att_gabt = att.get_annotations_between_timepoints
        return [att_gabt(brk0.time, brk1.time) for att in all_atts]

    word_list = [gabt(0, brk[0].time, all_atts)]
    for brk0, brk1 in zip(brk[:-1], brk[1:]):
        word_list.append(gabt(brk0.time, brk1.time, all_atts))
```

because it's in a class, the refactored code may look like this:

```
def _gabt(self, brk0, brk1):
    att_gabt = att.get_annotations_between_timepoints
    return [att_gabt(brk0.time, brk1.time) for att in self.all_attributes]

word_list = [self._gabt(0, brk[0].time)]
for brk0, brk1 in zip(brk[:-1], brk[1:]):
    word_list.append(self._gabt(brk0.time, brk1.time))
```